# encoding of the page mess up when including vbulletin global.php

Tags: php, utf-8

I am building a website and want to link it to vBulletin so i want to skip the duplicate user database and so on.

I have setup a proper char set on my page (utf-8) and used letters like ČĆĐŠ and everything works well. As soon as i include vBulletin global.php (so i can later access userid username and check if he is logged in) i get strange characters and not utf-8 :( like this Ä instead of č

As soon as i remove the include of global.php everthing is great
In my page source there is properly setuped

I've tried to put in php also
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
but no use :(

I've checked global.php is ANSI but i tried saving it as UTF-8 same thing